# EnterpriseLibrary.Logging terminates application

Tags: c#, logging, enterprise-library

We use some 3rd party software that is using Microsoft.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging
running as a service.

Recently that service stopped many times. We only have data from windows event log.
Stacktrace shows that an ArgumentNullException was thrown by MS EntLib Logging.

`Event Type:     Error
Event Source:   .NET Runtime
Event Category: None
Event ID:       1026
Date:           04/09/2012
Time:           19:05:23
User:           N/A
Computer:       XXX
Description:
Application: XXX.Service.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ArgumentNullException
Stack:
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogEntry.BuildCategoriesCollection(System.String)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Tracer.WriteTraceMessage(System.String, System.String, System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Tracer.WriteTraceEndMessage(System.String)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Tracer.Dispose(Boolean)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Tracer.Dispose()
   at XXX`

I have checked this and it looks like it is caused by:

`Trace.CorrelationManager.LogicalOperationStack.Peek()`

returning null

Can anyone help me why this happened?

Comment: Do you know which version of Enterprise Library that is used ?

Comment: Does this exception happen on a background thread?

Comment: Steven, yes this service runs multiple threads.

Comment: This [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/936233) seems to be the problem but it still hapens on 2.0 and above. Even on 4.0 on Win7

Comment: Do you have access to the third party code to know what they are doing internally?  Do you have a way without running the full application to reproduce the issue?  How did you run the .NET 2.0 assemblies in .NET 4?

Comment: Seems related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016383/c-sharp-enterpriselibrary-error/13945806 since they both have the same stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seem to be a known bug for E-Lib in previous versions too.

Known as: Unhandled exception when using the logging AB from multiple threads.

"The underlying issue is that in .NET 2.0 RTM a parent thread's operation stack was shared with its children if such a stack existed by the time the children were created."

Read more here: http://entlib.codeplex.com/workitem/9592

Hard to suggest a generic solution to this as it is very depends on the architecture of your app.